# set file permissions

Tags: permissions, files, directory, chown

I have a directory, where users can drop their plugins (for a game). The directory permissions work for adding these plugin files.

But there is one Problem: When the plugin generates config files, these files are not owned by the user who uploaded it, so the user who uploaded the plugin can not remove or edit these config files.

Can I make a standard owner? I would like to arrange it so that when these files are generated, they are owned by the "www-data" user. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more, what service(s) you are using? Is this a apache webserver you are talking about or something different?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setfacl`

```
setfacl -d -m group:rwx /path/to/config
```

Comment: It seems you need to activate the partition to accept acl for that to work.Even with that I would suggest to find out first what program writes the files and if there is a way to configure it to make them write with the intended owner before going down the acl road.